# Can I add a webpage (browser) to a visio diagram?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2016

Can I add a webpage(browser) to a Visio diagram?

Edit -- Additional Info:
I do not wish to add a hyperlink. I want to view the webpage in the diagram.

I know that there are webparts that can do this with Powerpoint,
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25946/how-to-add-live-web-pages-to-a-powerpoint-presentation/
so I am curious if this is also possible in Visio.

VBA solutions are fine.

Note: This is one approach to a broader question. My end goal is to get TFS (Team Foundation server) info into the diagram, but i thought it might be easier to just embed the TFS webpage rather than figure out how to query TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[web page display for Visio](http://www.paulherber.co.uk/articles/visio-articles/web-page-output/)

It's a Visio addon encapsulating an ActiveX control for displaying web pages. It doesn't do javascript and there are no buttons for Home, Back, Forward etc., just the display window.